# R How to Generate Sequences in a Tibble Given Start and End Points

Tags: r, tidyverse, sequence, generate, run-length-encoding

I can't think how to do this in a tidy fashion.

I have a table as follows:

```
tibble( 
  Min = c(1, 5, 12, 13, 19), 
  Max = c(3, 11, 12, 14, 19), 
  Value = c("a", "bb", "c", "d", "e" ) 
)
```

and I want to generate another table from it as shown below

```
tibble(
  Row = c(1:3, 5:11, 12:12, 13:14, 19:19), 
  Value = c( rep("a", 3), rep("bb", 7), "c", "d", "d", "e" ) 
)
```

Grateful for any suggestions folk might have.  The only 'solutions' which come to mind are a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If DF is the input then:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
 group_by(Value) %>%
 group_modify(~ tibble(Row = seq(.$Min, .$Max))) %>%
 ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 2
   Value   Row
   <chr> <int>
 1 a         1
 2 a         2
 3 a         3
 4 bb        5
 5 bb        6
 6 bb        7
 7 bb        8
 8 bb        9
 9 bb       10
10 bb       11
11 c        12
12 d        13
13 d        14
14 e        19
```

**2)** This one creates a list column L containing tibbles and then unnests it.  Duplicate `Value` elements are ok with this one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
 rowwise %>%
 summarize(L = list(tibble(Value, Row = seq(Min, Max)))) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 unnest(L)
```

Comment: Very nifty!  Would you mind clarifying exactly what happens in the line `group_modify(~ tibble(Row = seq(.$Min, .$Max)))`?  Now `tibble(Row = seq(.$Min, .$Max))` is obvious, but what happens under the hood when the formula `~ tibble(Row = seq(.$Min, .$Max))` is converted to a function and applied on a groupwise basis?  What gets altered or overwritten, and how?  I can't quite tie it together from the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html)...

Comment: For each Value the function is run producing a tibble, a Value column is added and they are all bound together.  dplyr used to have `do` for this purpose but `group_modify` superseded it.

Comment: Thank you!  I suppose that if there were multiple grouping columns (`Value_1` | `Value_2` | ... | `Value_n`), then all of those columns would be added to the resulting `tibble`, to the left of its existing column (`Value_1` | `Value_2` | ... | `Value_n` | `Row`)...

Comment: Yes, they would all be added.

Comment: That's so cool! Thanks very much. Just need to work out where I've gone wrong with my application of it now.  For some reason, I get the error "Error in seq.default(.$RowMin, .$RowMax) : 'from' must be of length 1".  I thought some of my Min values were bigger than the Max values, but I don't think they are.

Comment: @JamesBejon Any duplicate values in the `Value` column?  If so, I suspect some group (as grouped by `Value`) will have more than 1 row, so the `.$Min` for that group might be a vector of length greater than 1.  Since `seq()` (in `Row = seq(.$Min, .$Max)`) expects a scalar value as its first argument (for the parameter `from`), that might be causing your error: `'from' must be of length 1`.

Comment: Right.  Just realised.  Thanks.  When I use the input <<  tibble( Min = c(1, 5, 12, 13, 19), Max = c(3, 11, 12, 14, 19), Value = c("a", "bb", "c", "a", "e" ) )  >> I get the same issue.  The error message is the same with seq(1, NULL).  Any ideas for a fix?  Just add a dummy column from 1:nrow and group by both variables?

Comment: Something like this?  x %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(x)) %>%
    group_by(ID, Value) %>%
    group_modify(~ tibble(Row = seq(.$Min, .$Max))) %>%
    ungroup()

Comment: @JamesBejon Since you're already using `library(dplyr)`, you can simply do `x %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% ...`, which is a bit cleaner than `1:nrow(x)`.

Comment: Have added a second approach. It can handle duplicate Value's without change.

Comment: That really is clean!  Thanks so much!!  I need to work with multiple value columns, but R was quite happy to do << summarise(L = list(tibble(across(contains("Hebrew")), RowNumber = seq(RowMin, RowMax)))) >>